# compiler determine argument is given or omitted

Tags: c++, function, default-arguments

How to determine / check whether a function argument is given or omitted in compile time?

```
bool a_function(char* b, size_t len=0) {

      // no run time check such as if (len ......
      // just compile time check

      // ...
}
```

How to realize it?

Comment: you write 2 different functions...

Comment: They're always provided - the caller uses the default values as given in the function declaration and then calls the function in the normal way.

Answer (score 6):

No, there's no way to know (even at run-time) the argument was specified or not for parameter with default argument in the function.

You can apply overloading, e.g.

```
bool a_function(char* b, size_t len) {

    // len is specified
    // do something...
}
bool a_function(char* b) {

    // len is not specified
    // do something else...
    // or call a_function with len=0 (the default value) if satisfying the requirement
}
```

Comment: ...and, to reduce possible code duplication, the 2nd function still could call the 1st after having determined the `len` somehow.

Comment: Yes, default arguments are (mostly/entirely?) syntactic sugar for combining those two functions into a single one, _specifically_ for the case where you don't care if the argument is defaulted or not. Not using that syntactic sugar is exactly what is called for here.